# One step process file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When a user wants to upload a file (currently there are 4 places in the form that allow for this), they first have to “Choose File” and then they have to click on “Upload”. If they miss the 2nd "Upload" step, there is no indication to them or us.

Is there a way to combine the “two-step” process to a single step (select and upload).

Comment: There is 4 upload inputs. Is it possible just to select the files for all the inputs and just click the upload button once

Answer (score 3):

Use this link to know more about it

```
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/
```

And you can also use this code

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="upload" style="display:none" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isfirst = true;
        $(function () {

            $('#<%= fileupload1.ClientID %>').on('change', function (e) {
                console.log('change triggered');
                $('#<%= btn.ClientID%>').trigger('click'); // trigger the btn button click which i have hidden using style='display:none'
            });
        });

    </script>
    </form>
</body>
Code behind

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO 
}
```

Comment: There is 4 upload inputs. Is it possible just to select the files for all the inputs and just click the upload button once